# Target WooCommerce submit button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hook into the WooCommerce submit button and applying some custom jQuery scripts before submitting the order. However,I can't seem to target the submit button on the checkout page. I have tried the following:

```
jQuery('form[name="checkout"]').submit(function(event) {
  alert( "Checkout submit!" );
  console.log('test');
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

And

```
jQuery('#place_order').on("click",function() {
  alert( "Checkout submit!" );
  console.log('test');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

None of which seems to work. Any ideas? The name of the form is checkout, and the id of the submit button is place_order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy the woo-commerce checkout.js and paste in your theme folder and add following code in your function.php

and after then you can change the checkout.js from your them.

```
function so_27023433_disable_checkout_script(){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
    wp_enqueue_script('checkout',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/checkout.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_27023433_disable_checkout_script' );
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the file and did as you said. I am still not sure where exactly to put the code, though. What I would like to achieve before submitting to order is something like this:

`if ( jQuery("#shipping_method_0_local_delivery").is(":checked") ) { 

 var fornavn = jQuery("#billing_first_name").val();
 var efternavn = jQuery("#billing_last_name").val();

 jQuery("#shipping_first_name").val(fornavn);
 jQuery("#shipping_last_name").val(efternavn);
}`

I guess I should put this inside a function, and then call the function somewhere before submitting. But where?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Ok, well. I got it to work. Kind of .. But as soon as I replace checkout.js per your instructions, other jQuery on the page seems to stop working.

The "send to other address" checkbox doesnt respond anymore, fields doesn't turn red when nothing is written in them, and the coupon code button doesnt work either. Any ideas on how to fix this?